# css flex layout not working on some iPads

Tags: html, css, ipad, flexbox

I am having some issues with flex on the ipad. I want three equally spaced boxes. Its working fine on my ipad, and various browsers (inc safari on desktop) However, some iPads are showing that the boxes have no space between them and are all ranged left. I can't reproduce this however.

Here's the html

```
<aside id="home-page-postcards" class="home-page-postcards" role="complementary">
  <div class="postcard-wrapper">
    <div class="postcard">...content...</div>
    <div class="postcard">...content...</div>
    <div class="postcard">...content...</div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

I have this css;

```
.home-page-postcards {
    background:#fff;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:60px;
    padding-top:35px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
}


.postcard-wrapper { 
        display: -webkit-box;      
        display: -moz-box;         
        display: -ms-flexbox;      
        display: -webkit-flex;     
        display: flex;             

        width:1170px;
        margin:0 auto;

        -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
        flex-flow:row nowrap;

        -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        justify-content: space-between;
        }

.postcard {
    width:31.2%;
    font-family: 'Belleza', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:1.3;
}
```

Comment: just to add there is a media query like this: @media (max-width:1171px){ .postcard-wrapper {width:100%;}...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are missing the 2009 `-webkit-box` syntax for `justify-content: space-between`. Older iPads with Safari < 6.1 need  `-webkit-box-pack: justify;`.

For flexbox back-compat, you need to use the 2 additional syntaxes for all non-default properties, including `-moz-` and `-ms-` prefixes for all browsers.

Your wrapper should be:

```
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
```

See this [demo and flexbox generator](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&legacy=on&display=flex&flex-direction=row&flex-wrap=nowrap&justify-content=space-between&align-items=flex-start&align-content=space-between&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto) for help with your complete cross-browser syntax.

PS: Note that this tool will generate the full set of properties. Some of which you may not need, if already the "flexbox" default. In this case you don't need `row` or `nowrap`. It's already the flex default.