# How to center align image on navbar and for small device move it to the left to fit content?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a logo image with some transparency in it.  How can I align the logo image to the center on the fixed navbar and then move it slightly to the left on smaller devices so that the content on the right can fit on the navbar?

I have tried `background-size: cover` but makes the image responsive and the logo gets cut off.  I tried `background-size: contain` but then I lose the background color of the navbar on larger devices.

Is there a way I can move the image to the html to achieve what I need?

Here is my attempt on plnkr: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/Uij12vHwFuaeAS91nYUL?p=preview

thanks

**UPDATE:**

I am trying a different approach and moved the image into the html and try to use the css flexbox approach. Almost there, but need to remove the gap.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="search">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </div>
      <a class="brand-logo" href="#/">
        <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/1963cc1736.png" />
      </a>
      <aside>
       <figure class="account-balance">
         <span>de 88,980.7740</span>
         <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </figure>
      </aside>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
nav.navbar {
border: 0;
color: #FFF;
height: 40px;
min-height: 40px;
z-index: 1;
display: 0;
-webkit-box-pack: justify;
-moz-box-pack: justify;
-webkit-justify-content: space-between;
-ms-flex-pack: justify;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.search,.filler,aside,figure {
    height: 100%;
}

.search,.filler,aside {
    background: #266224;
    float: left;
}

.search,aside {
    flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
}

.search .fa-search,figure > span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.search {
    padding: 0 12px;
}

.brand-logo img {
    height: 40px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

figure {
    float: right;
}

figure.account-balance {
    padding-right: 12px;
}

figure > span {
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Here is the modified version using flexbox:
https://embed.plnkr.co/wSWpIDIoJOiSQYVvwHMU/

This does come close to resolving the problem however, this is not working well on iPhone 6 and old iPad.

There is a slight gap on either side of the anchor tag (maybe half a pixel gap), I have tried the solution mentioned here: [css flex layout not working on some iPads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296836/css-flex-layout-not-working-on-some-ipads) but it doesn’t work.

Do you know a way to remove the gap?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write specified styles for different device width [using this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

Comment: thanks, i have tried using media queries to adjust the image for smaller devices however it doesn't resolve the issue when viewing on large screens, when using background cover the image is distorted and does not fit within the navbar.  When using background: contain, the image fits within the bar but then you see a large gap missing.  I cannot apply background color to the whole navbar as the image has some transparency in it

Comment: That sounds more like an issue with the image itself, not the position of it. What format is your image in? SVG would be the most appropriate if you want to show it with a crisp resolution both on a big and a small screen

Comment: I am using a png.  If I use a SVG will the logo fit within the navbar?  the navbar has a fixed height of 40px, when using background cover, the image expands beyond the height of the navbar.

Comment: If your navbar has a fixed height so should your logo. There is no point in resizing the logo if the container around it does not resize. Have a logo with a fixed height and width and only adjust its position based on the size of the screen.

Comment: I have tried using background cover with min-height and max-width as applying  fixed height and width does not work.    With min-height and max-width and the image slightly moves up and gets cut off and when the screen size is larger than 800px the navbar no longer expands to the full width of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ul li {
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    background: #f6304c;
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2% 0 0 30%;
    padding: 50px 0;
}
```

for mobile device

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 678px) {
        ul li {
            height: 180px;
            width: 180px;
            background: #f6304c;
            display: block;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-align: center;
            float:left;
           / margin: 2% 0 0 30%;*/
            padding: 50px 0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, but I am referring to the green navbar bar at the top, with the "mobile.av" logo image.  Ignore the content under the green navbar.

Comment: hey zincy it's sole your problem for ui->li ?

Comment: The problem is on the navbar not for ul > li

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
.brand-logo {
    background: url(https://i.imgsafe.org/1963cc1736.png) left center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #266224;
    height: 100%;
}
```

the only thing you have to do is fill the O in your logo with the color because it is transparent XD

Comment: thanks Rudi, but I cannot apply a background color as the intention is to keep the O in the image transparent.  Annoying, as it is but that's what the expectation is.

Comment: hm than the only way i see is to add a gradient background changing color were your o is located

Comment: something like this background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #266224 34%,#fdeda3 35%,#fdeda3 63%,#266224 64%);